# How to start calendar_for week on Monday instead of Sunday?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, calendar, rubygems

I was following the railscast http://railscasts.com/episodes/213-calendars and I use the following gem instead of script/plugin install 
https://github.com/jchunky/table_builder

The output is fine.. displays me a nice calendar! (thanks ryan)
but I would like to know how to modify this code to make the week displayed starting on mondays instead of sundays:

```
<div id="calendar">
  <h2 id="month">
    <%= link_to "<", :month => (@date.beginning_of_month-1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
    <%=h @date.strftime("%B %Y") %>
    <%= link_to ">", :month => (@date.end_of_month+1).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") %>
  </h2>
  <% calendar_for @hours, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month do |calendar| %>
    <%= calendar.head('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday') %>
    <% calendar.day(:day_method => :date) do |date, hours| %>
      <%= date.day %>
      <ul>
        <% for hour in hours %>
          <li><%= link_to h(hour.task), hour %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: did you try giving `'Monday'` as the first string in the line `<%= calendar.head('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday') %>`?

Comment: yep, this only changes the header unfortunately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the code, there is a `:first_day_of_week` option. Just set it to 1 = Monday

```
calendar_for @hours, :year => @date.year, :month => @date.month, :first_day_of_week => 1 do |calendar|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set [`Date.beginning_of_week`](https://apidock.com/rails/Date/beginning_of_week/class) globally.